# Use two variables to select from array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is it possible to use varName1[varName2] to retrieve a value from an array.  In the example below, .el is a select box, thisVal might = 2 and thisName = 'B' which should result in the answer 'U' in fact I am getting undefined

```
<script>
var A = ['B','B','Z','Z']
var B = ['C','O','U','C2','C3','D']
var C = ['D','Z','D','Z']
  $('.el').on('change', function() {
    var thisVal = this.value
    var thisName = this.name
    var nextName = thisName[thisVal]
    alert( nextName );
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you arrays are in the global scope, you can use.

```
window[thisName][thisVal]
```

Example

```js
var A = ['B','B','Z','Z'];
var B = ['C','O','U','C2','C3','D'];
var C = ['D','Z','D','Z'];

var thisVal = 2;
var thisName = 'B';

console.log(window[thisName][thisVal]);
```

As an alternative you can use an object to store your arrays and instead of the `window` use your object.

Example

```js
const obj = {
  A: ['B','B','Z','Z'],
  B: ['C','O','U','C2','C3','D'],
  C: ['D','Z','D','Z']
}

const thisVal = 2;
const thisName = 'B';

console.log(obj[thisName][thisVal]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> which should result in the answer 'U' in fact I am getting undefined

That is not applicable for javascript and undefined is *exactly* what it should return

You can use [javascript eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) for this purpose

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
var x= 'a';
var y=2;
console.log(x+'['+y+']')  // "a[2]"
console.log(eval(x+'['+y+']'))  // 3
```